# line break or simplify or make long payload data line by line without error

Tags: go, line

I had a variable `payload`, it is too long here just a part.

```
payload := strings.NewReader("json=%7B%22rent_content_layout%22%3A%22Original%22%2C%22start_verylargetext_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22auto_large_mode")
```

is any way to make the one line var data to multi line or make it human readable using golang, for bash or shell we use `\n`, is any trick to line break it using golang

Comment: what do you mean you would use `\n`? Do you want to add newlines into the string? If you want to break up the long string, just do that and concatenate the parts with `+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do the string concatenation with the `+` operator and break the string into small parts.

```
payload := strings.NewReader(
        "json=%7B%22" +
        "rent_content_layout%22%3A%22" +
        "Original%22%2C%22" +
        "start_verylargetext_enabled%22%3A" +
        "false%2C%22auto_large_mode")
```